# How to write an async method with out parameter?

Tags: c#, async-await, out

I want to write an async method with an `out` parameter, like this:

```
public async void Method1()
{
    int op;
    int result = await GetDataTaskAsync(out op);
}
```

How do I do this in `GetDataTaskAsync`?

Answer (score 418, accepted):

You can't have async methods with `ref` or `out` parameters.

Lucian Wischik explains why this is not possible on this MSDN thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2f48a52-e35a-4948-844d-828a1a6deb74/why-async-methods-cannot-have-ref-or-out-parameters (Original post is no longer available due to link rot, [latest archived version can be found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230606133342/https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2f48a52-e35a-4948-844d-828a1a6deb74/why-async-methods-cannot-have-ref-or-out-parameters).)

> As for why async methods don't support out-by-reference parameters?
> (or ref parameters?) That's a limitation of the CLR. We chose to
> implement async methods in a similar way to iterator methods -- i.e.
> through the compiler transforming the method into a
> state-machine-object. The CLR has no safe way to store the address of
> an "out parameter" or "reference parameter" as a field of an object.
> The only way to have supported out-by-reference parameters would be if
> the async feature were done by a low-level CLR rewrite instead of a
> compiler-rewrite. We examined that approach, and it had a lot going
> for it, but it would ultimately have been so costly that it'd never
> have happened.

A typical workaround for this situation is to have the async method return a Tuple instead.
You could re-write your method as such:

```
public async Task Method1()
{
    var tuple = await GetDataTaskAsync();
    int op = tuple.Item1;
    int result = tuple.Item2;
}

public async Task<Tuple<int, int>> GetDataTaskAsync()
{
    //...
    return new Tuple<int, int>(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Far from being too complex, this could produce too many problem. Jon Skeet explained it very well here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868103/ref-and-out-arguments-in-async-method

Comment: I think [Named Tuples](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2016/07/25/tuples-in-c-7/) in C# 7 will be the perfect solution for this.

Comment: @orad I especially like this: private async Task<(bool success, Job job, string message)> TryGetJobAsync(...)

Comment: why doesn't the compiler create the tuple behind the scenes?

Comment: Tuple return values, named or not, are a code smell in my book because they tend to accumulate new members until they become unwieldy. Plus you have no inheritance chain, so if you want to write code to operate on the differently-shaped tuple return values of your methods, you're out of luck (and you also have the opposite problem that your code isn't specific enough to your methods). tl;dr using tuples as retvals is barely a step up from `dynamic` - C# is an OOP language so use a proper class to allow inheritance, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23891335/70345

Comment: To be more succinct, you could unpack the tuple in one line: var (op, result) = await GetDataTaskAsync();

Answer (score 108):

[The C#7+ Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt493248.aspx) is to use implicit tuple syntax.

```
    private async Task<(bool IsSuccess, IActionResult Result)> TryLogin(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    { 
        return (true, BadRequest(new OpenIdErrorResponse
        {
            Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.AccessDenied,
            ErrorDescription = "Access token provided is not valid."
        }));
    }
```

return result utilizes the method signature defined property names. e.g:

```
var foo = await TryLogin(request);
if (foo.IsSuccess)
     return foo.Result;
```

Comment: why are you hardcoding "true" as your "isSuccess" return value but returning BadRequest as the result, though?

Comment: Returning a named tuple of this form is very similar to returning an `Either` type, which are common in functional languages. Haskell has one, for example: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html.

The `LanguageExt` package for C# has one too (and a lot of other functional extensions):
https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/Monads/Alternative%20Value%20Monads/Either/Either/index.html. Another alternative would be to return an `Option` type, if you expect 0 or 1 things to come back (i.e. for handling `TryGetValue` on a Dictionary, for example).

Answer (score 65):

You cannot have `ref` or `out` parameters in `async` methods (as was already noted).

This screams for some modelling in the data moving around:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Op {get; set;}
    public int Result {get; set;}
}

public async void Method1()
{
    Data data = await GetDataTaskAsync();
    // use data.Op and data.Result from here on
}

public async Task<Data> GetDataTaskAsync()
{
    var returnValue = new Data();
    // Fill up returnValue
    return returnValue;
}
```

You gain the ability to reuse your code more easily, plus it's way more readable than variables or tuples.

Comment: I prefer this solution instead using a Tuple. More clean!

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem as I like using the Try-method-pattern which basically seems to be incompatible to the async-await-paradigm...

Important to me is that I can call the Try-method within a single if-clause and do not have to pre-define the out-variables before, but can do it in-line like in the following example:

```
if (TryReceive(out string msg))
{
    // use msg
}
```

So I came up with the following solutions:

Note: The new solution is superior, because it can be used with methods that simply return a tuple as described in many of the other answers here, what might often be found in existing code!

### New solution:

1. Create extension methods for ValueTuples:

   ```
   public static class TupleExtensions
   {
     public static bool TryOut<P2>(this ValueTuple<bool, P2> tuple, out P2 p2)
     {
        bool p1;
        (p1, p2) = tuple;
        return p1;
     }

     public static bool TryOut<P2, P3>(this ValueTuple<bool, P2, P3> tuple, out P2 p2, out P3 p3)
     {
        bool p1;
        (p1, p2, p3) = tuple;
        return p1;
     }

     // continue to support larger tuples...
   }
   ```
2. Define async Try-method like this:

   ```
    public async Task<(bool, string)> TryReceiveAsync()
    {
        string message;
        bool success;
        // ...
        return (success, message);
    }
   ```
3. Call the async Try-method like this:

   ```
    if ((await TryReceiveAsync()).TryOut(out string msg))
    {
        // use msg
    }
   ```

---

### Old solution:

1. Define a helper struct:

   ```
    public struct AsyncOut<T, OUT>
    {
        private readonly T returnValue;
        private readonly OUT result;

        public AsyncOut(T returnValue, OUT result)
        {
            this.returnValue = returnValue;
            this.result = result;
        }

        public T Out(out OUT result)
        {
            result = this.result;
            return returnValue;
        }

        public T ReturnValue => returnValue;

        public static implicit operator AsyncOut<T, OUT>((T returnValue ,OUT result) tuple) => 
            new AsyncOut<T, OUT>(tuple.returnValue, tuple.result);
    }
   ```
2. Define async Try-method like this:

   ```
    public async Task<AsyncOut<bool, string>> TryReceiveAsync()
    {
        string message;
        bool success;
        // ...
        return (success, message);
    }
   ```
3. Call the async Try-method like this:

   ```
    if ((await TryReceiveAsync()).Out(out string msg))
    {
        // use msg
    }
   ```

For multiple out parameters you can define additional structs (e.g. AsyncOut<T,OUT1, OUT2>) or you can return a tuple.

Comment: How is this not one of the top answers, this solution provides parity with the non async version unlike other anwsers that have you return a tuple and then run your if block.

Comment: Fyi, this is the only answer here that is "in keeping" with the non-async Try pattern. The use of Tuples and ValueTuples is not at all in keeping.

Answer (score 16):

Alex made a great point on readability.  Equivalently, a function is also interface enough to define the type(s) being returned and you also get meaningful variable names.

```
delegate void OpDelegate(int op);
Task<bool> GetDataTaskAsync(OpDelegate callback)
{
    bool canGetData = true;
    if (canGetData) callback(5);
    return Task.FromResult(canGetData);
}
```

Callers provide a lambda (or a named function) and intellisense helps by copying the variable name(s) from the delegate.

```
int myOp;
bool result = await GetDataTaskAsync(op => myOp = op);
```

This particular approach is like a "Try" method where `myOp` is set if the method result is `true`. Otherwise, you don't care about `myOp`.

Answer (score 11):

I love the `Try` pattern. It's a tidy pattern.

```
if (double.TryParse(name, out var result))
{
    // handle success
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

But, it's challenging with `async`. That doesn't mean we don't have real options. Here are the three core approaches you can consider for `async` methods in a quasi-version of the `Try` pattern.

### Approach 1 - output a structure

This looks most like a sync `Try` method only returning a `tuple` instead of a `bool` with an `out` parameter, which we all know is not permitted in C#.

```
var result = await DoAsync(name);
if (result.Success)
{
    // handle success
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

With a method that returns `true` of `false` and never throws an `exception`.

> Remember, throwing an exception in a `Try` method breaks the whole purpose of the pattern.

```
async Task<(bool Success, StorageFile File, Exception exception)> DoAsync(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder;
        return (true, await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName), null);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return (false, null, exception);
    }
}
```

### Approach 2 - pass in callback methods

We can use `anonymous` methods to set external variables. It's clever syntax, though slightly complicated. In small doses, it's fine.

```
var file = default(StorageFile);
var exception = default(Exception);
if (await DoAsync(name, x => file = x, x => exception = x))
{
    // handle success
}
else
{
    // handle failure
}
```

The method obeys the basics of the `Try` pattern but sets `out` parameters to passed in callback methods. It's done like this.

```
async Task<bool> DoAsync(string fileName, Action<StorageFile> file, Action<Exception> error)
{
    try
    {
        var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder;
        file?.Invoke(await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        error?.Invoke(exception);
        return false;
    }
}
```

> There's a question in my mind about performance here. But, the C# compiler is so freaking smart, that I think you're safe choosing this option, almost for sure.

### Approach 3 - use ContinueWith

What if you just use the `TPL` as designed? No tuples. The idea here is that we use exceptions to redirect `ContinueWith` to two different paths.

```
await DoAsync(name).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    if (task.Exception != null)
    {
        // handle fail
    }
    if (task.Result is StorageFile sf)
    {
        // handle success
    }
});
```

With a method that throws an `exception` when there is any kind of failure. That's different than returning a `boolean`. It's a way to communicate with the `TPL`.

```
async Task<StorageFile> DoAsync(string fileName)
{
    var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder;
    return await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
}
```

In the code above, if the file is not found, an exception is thrown. This will invoke the failure `ContinueWith` that will handle `Task.Exception` in its logic block. Neat, huh?

> Listen, there's a reason we love the `Try` pattern. It's fundamentally so neat and readable and, as a result, maintainable. As you choose your approach, watchdog for readability. Remember the next developer who in 6 months and doesn't have you to answer clarifying questions. Your code can be the only documentation a developer will ever have.

Best of luck.

Comment: About the third approach, are you sure that chaining `ContinueWith` calls has the expected outcome? According to my understanding the second `ContinueWith` will check the success of the first continuation, not the success of the original task.

Comment: Throwing exceptions for flow control is a massive code smell for me - it's going to tank your performance.

Comment: No, @IanKemp, that's a pretty old concept. The compiler has evolved.

Comment: I really like approach 2 here.

Comment: It's 2021 and throwing exceptions for flow control is *still* bad for performance; .NET Core maintainers consider any caught first-chance exceptions to be addressed if at all possible.

Answer (score 9):

One nice feature of `out` parameters is that they can be used to return data even when a function throws an exception. I think the closest equivalent to doing this with an `async` method would be using a new object to hold the data that both the `async` method and caller can refer to. Another way would be to [pass a delegate as suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515539/429091).

Note that neither of these techniques will have any of the sort of enforcement from the compiler that `out` has. I.e., the compiler won’t require you to set the value on the shared object or call a passed in delegate.

Here’s an example implementation using a shared object to imitate `ref` and `out` for use with `async` methods and other various scenarios where `ref` and `out` aren’t available:

```
class Ref<T>
{
    // Field rather than a property to support passing to functions
    // accepting `ref T` or `out T`.
    public T Value;
}

async Task OperationExampleAsync(Ref<int> successfulLoopsRef)
{
    var things = new[] { 0, 1, 2, };
    var i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // Fourth iteration will throw an exception, but we will still have
        // communicated data back to the caller via successfulLoopsRef.
        things[i] += i;
        successfulLoopsRef.Value++;
        i++;
    }
}

async Task UsageExample()
{
    var successCounterRef = new Ref<int>();
    // Note that it does not make sense to access successCounterRef
    // until OperationExampleAsync completes (either fails or succeeds)
    // because there’s no synchronization. Here, I think of passing
    // the variable as “temporarily giving ownership” of the referenced
    // object to OperationExampleAsync. Deciding on conventions is up to
    // you and belongs in documentation ^^.
    try
    {
        await OperationExampleAsync(successCounterRef);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Had {successCounterRef.Value} successful loops.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's the code of @dcastro's answer modified for C# 7.0 with named tuples and tuple deconstruction, which streamlines the notation:

```
public async void Method1()
{
    // Version 1, named tuples:
    // just to show how it works
    /*
    var tuple = await GetDataTaskAsync();
    int op = tuple.paramOp;
    int result = tuple.paramResult;
    */

    // Version 2, tuple deconstruction:
    // much shorter, most elegant
    (int op, int result) = await GetDataTaskAsync();
}

public async Task<(int paramOp, int paramResult)> GetDataTaskAsync()
{
    //...
    return (1, 2);
}
```

For details about the new named tuples, tuple literals and tuple deconstructions see:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/

Answer (score 6):

The limitation of the `async` methods not accepting `out` parameters applies only to the compiler-generated async methods, these declared with the `async` keyword. It doesn't apply to hand-crafted async methods. In other words it is possible to create `Task` returning methods accepting `out` parameters. For example lets say that we already have a `ParseIntAsync` method that throws, and we want to create a `TryParseIntAsync` that doesn't throw. We could implement it like this:

```
public static Task<bool> TryParseIntAsync(string s, out Task<int> result)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    result = tcs.Task;
    return ParseIntAsync(s).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            tcs.SetException(t.Exception.InnerException);
            return false;
        }
        tcs.SetResult(t.Result);
        return true;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Using the [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) and the [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method is a bit awkward, but there is no other option since we can't use the convenient `await` keyword inside this method.

Usage example:

```
if (await TryParseIntAsync("-13", out var result))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {await result}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Parse failed");
}
```

---

**Update:** If the async logic is too complex to be expressed without `await`, then it could be encapsulated inside a nested asynchronous anonymous delegate. A `TaskCompletionSource` would still be needed for the `out` parameter. It is possible that the `out` parameter could be completed before
the completion of the main task, as in the example bellow:

```
public static Task<string> GetDataAsync(string url, out Task<int> rawDataLength)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    rawDataLength = tcs.Task;
    return ((Func<Task<string>>)(async () =>
    {
        var response = await GetResponseAsync(url);
        var rawData = await GetRawDataAsync(response);
        tcs.SetResult(rawData.Length);
        return await FilterDataAsync(rawData);
    }))();
}
```

This example assumes the existence of three asynchronous methods `GetResponseAsync`, `GetRawDataAsync` and `FilterDataAsync` that are called
in succession. The `out` parameter is completed on the completion of the second method. The `GetDataAsync` method could be used like this:

```
var data = await GetDataAsync("http://example.com", out var rawDataLength);
Console.WriteLine($"Data: {data}");
Console.WriteLine($"RawDataLength: {await rawDataLength}");
```

Awaiting the `data` before awaiting the `rawDataLength` is important in this simplified example, because in case of an exception the `out` parameter will never be completed.

Comment: This is a very nice solution for some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Pattern matching to the rescue! C#9 (I think) onwards:

```
// example of a method that would traditionally would use an out parameter
public async Task<(bool success, int? value)> TryGetAsync()
{
    int? value = // get it from somewhere
    
    return (value.HasValue, value);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (await TryGetAsync() is (true, int value))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"This is the value: {value}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using ValueTuples like this can work.  You have to add the ValueTuple NuGet package first though:

```
public async void Method1()
{
    (int op, int result) tuple = await GetDataTaskAsync();
    int op = tuple.op;
    int result = tuple.result;
}

public async Task<(int op, int result)> GetDataTaskAsync()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    return (op: x, result: y):
}
```

Comment: You don’t need the NuGet if using .net-4.7 or netstandard-2.0.

Comment: Hey, you're right!  I just uninstalled that NuGet package and it still works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to the answer provided by Michael Gehling, but I had my own solution until I found his and noticed that I wasn't the first to think of using an implicit conversion.

Regardless, I wanted to share as mine also supports when `nullable` is set to `enable`

```
public readonly struct TryResult<TOut>
{
    #region constructors

    public TryResult(bool success, TOut? value) => (Success, Value) = (success, value);

    #endregion

    #region properties

    public                                            bool  Success { get; init; }
    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(Success))] public TOut? Value   { get; init; }

    #endregion

    #region methods

    public static implicit operator bool(TryResult<TOut> result) => result.Success;
    public static implicit operator TryResult<TOut>(TOut value) => new (true, value);

    public void Deconstruct(out bool success, out TOut? value) => (success, value) = (Success, Value);

    public TryResult<TOut> Out([NotNullWhen(true)] out TOut? value)
    {
        value = Value;

        return this;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then you can write a Try method like this:

```
public static async Task<TryResult<byte[]>> TryGetBytesAsync(string file) =>
    File.Exists(file)
        ? await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(file)
        : default(TryResult<byte[]>);
```

And call it like this:

```
if ((await TryGetBytesAsync(file)).Out(out var bytes))
    Console.WriteLine($"File has {bytes.Length} bytes.");
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents. It is similar to the tuple examples, just with a generic interface and a class implementation.

```
public interface ITryGetResult<T>
{
  bool WasSuccessful { get; }
  T Value { get; }
}

public class TryGetResultModel<T> : ITryGetResult<T>
{
  public bool WasSuccessful { get; private set; }
  public T Value { get; private set; }

  public static TryGetResultModel<T> Success(T result)
  {
    return new TryGetResultModel<T>()
    {
      WasSuccessful = true,
      Value = result
    };
  }

  // Is diffrent for each TryGetResultModel<T>
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647641/resharper-warns-static-field-in-generic-type
  public static TryGetResultModel<T> Failed = new TryGetResultModel<T>();
}
```

Usage example

```
public async Task<ITryGetResult<string>> TryGetAsync()
{
  result = await GetAsync();

  return result == default
    ? TryGetResultModel<string>.Failed
    : TryGetResultModel<string>.Success(result);
}

public async Task Main()
{
  var result = await TryGetAsync();

  if (result.WasSuccessful)
  {
    DoSomething(result.Value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For developers who REALLY want to keep it in parameter, here might be another workaround.

Change the parameter to an array or List to wrap the actual value up. Remember to initialize the list before sending into the method. After returned, be sure to check value existence before consuming it. Code with caution.

Answer (score -7):

You can do this by using TPL (task parallel library) instead of direct using await keyword.

```
private bool CheckInCategory(int? id, out Category category)
    {
        if (id == null || id == 0)
            category = null;
        else
            category = Task.Run(async () => await _context.Categories.FindAsync(id ?? 0)).Result;

        return category != null;
    }

if(!CheckInCategory(int? id, out var category)) return error
```

Comment: Never use .Result. It's an anti-pattern. Thanks!

Comment: This method is not asynchronous.  It does not answer the question.