# ref and out arguments in async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Does anyone know why `async` methods are not allowed to have `ref` and `out` arguments? I've done a bit of research on it but the only thing I could find was that it has to do with the stack unrolling.

Comment: I think that you can find the answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716928/how-to-write-a-async-method-with-out-parameter

Comment: Take a look at servy42's answer from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df2b3fb6-000b-438f-a32d-a0504ee66e77/whats-the-reason-that-async-methods-cant-have-outref-parameters

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2f48a52-e35a-4948-844d-828a1a6deb74/why-async-methods-cannot-have-ref-or-out-parameters?forum=async

Comment: Related: [How to write an async method with out parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716928/how-to-write-a-async-method-with-out-parameter)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

> Does anyone know why async methods are not allowed to have ref and out arguments?

Sure. Think about it - an async method usually *returns* almost immediately, long before most of the actual logic is executed... that's done asynchronously. So any `out` parameters would have to be assigned before the first `await` expression, and there'd quite possibly have to be some restriction on `ref` parameters to stop them from being used after the first `await` expression anyway, as after that they may not even be valid.

Consider calling an async method with `out` and `ref` parameters, using local variables for the arguments:

```
int x;
int y = 10;
FooAsync(out x, ref y);
```

After `FooAsync` returns, the method itself could return - so those local variables would no longer logically exist... but the async method would still effectively be able to use them in its continuations. Big problems. The compiler could create a new class to capture the variable in the same way that it does for lambda expressions, but that would cause other issues... aside from anything else, you could have a *local* variable changing at arbitrary points through a method, when continuations run on a different thread. Odd to say the least.

Basically, it doesn't make sense to use `out` and `ref` parameters for `async` methods, due to the timing involved. Use a return type which includes all of the data you're interested in instead.

If you're only interested in the `out` and `ref` parameters changing before the first `await` expression, you can always split the method in two:

```
public Task<string> FooAsync(out int x, ref int y)
{
    // Assign a value to x here, maybe change y
    return FooAsyncImpl(x, y);
}

private async Task<string> FooAsyncImpl(int x, int y) // Not ref or out!
{
}
```

EDIT: It would be feasible to have `out` parameters using `Task<T>` and assign the value directly within the method just like return values. It would be a bit odd though, and it wouldn't work for `ref` parameters.

Comment: @hvd: Yes, it could potentially do that - will edit to include that as a possibility. Although it couldn't do that to pass one `out` parameter as an argument for another `out` parameter...

Comment: Sure, that's a good point. It could pass the reference passed in, but if *that* refers to a local variable not wrapped in a class, you still have the same problem.

Comment: I think I was mistaken, and that it's just plain impossible without extensions to CIL.

Comment: I don't get it, did you mean `Action<T>` instead of `Task<T>`? If so, nice idea.

Comment: @hvd: No, I mean Task. Think of it as just another return value - the task wouldn't complete until the whole method had completed, at which point the value would be the last one assigned in the method. Bit odd, but feasible.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant what would effectively be `await FooAsyncImpl(val => x = val, val => y = val)` instead of `await FooAsyncImpl(out x, out y)`, which would also work for `out` and only for `out` (and you don't read it after setting it). Thanks for the clarification, I'm still not sure I get it, but I'll think about it. :)

Answer (score 31):

C# is compiled to CIL, and CIL does not support this.

CIL does not have `async` natively. `async` methods are compiled to a class, and all (used) parameters and local variables are stored in class fields, so that when a specific method of that class is called, the code knows where to continue executing and what values the variables have.

`ref` and `out` parameters are implemented using managed pointers, and class fields of managed pointer type are not allowed, so the compiler cannot preserve the reference passed in.

This restriction on managed pointers in class fields prevents some nonsensical code, as explained in Jon Skeet's answer, as a managed pointer in a class field might refer to a local variable of a function that has already returned. However, this restriction is so strict that even safe and otherwise correct usage is rejected. The `ref`/`out` fields *could* work, if they referred to another class field, and the compiler made sure to always wrap local variables passed with `ref`/`out` in a class (like it already knows how to do).

So, C# simply does not have any way to work around the restrictions imposed by CIL. Even if the C# designers want to allow it (I'm not saying they do), they cannot.