# Put reference on a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, ref

Is there any way I could put this method on a different thread?

I've tried putting the functions inside a Thread, but I cannot use the ref keyword in them.
I've also tried making the method asynchronous, but those don't support ref either.
It works if I call the function like this:

```
new Thread(() => x.Animate(0f, 1f, 1000, Ease.Linear)).Start();
```

but this seems inconvenient.

```
    public static void Animate(this ref float value, float start, float change, int duration, Ease easing)
    {
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds <= duration)
        {
                value = easing.Execute((int)timer.ElapsedMilliseconds, start, change, duration);
        }
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: Conversely, if you want it on a separate thread, why do you want `value` to be `ref`?

Comment: @escept [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18716968/986184) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20868150/986184)

Comment: I don't really need it to be on a new thread, I just need any way to not hang the calling thread while looping

Answer (score -1):

If you want to track the variable `value`, you can make a class level public static property of it instead of a ref parameter.

You should separate that concern into another property or a single instance class.