# make a return function with await

Tags: c#, mongodb

Hi guys i did some code to get list of databases that exists in mongodb server.
the list is stored in lst i want to make the function give back a result so i used out .
here is the first method it works fine

```
public static async void listDatabases()
{
    List<string> lst = null;
    try
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
        //MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
        // List<string> lstdatabases = server.GetDatabaseNames().ToList();
        using (var cursor = client.ListDatabasesAsync())
        {
            await cursor.Result.ForEachAsync(d => lst.Add(d.GetElement(0).Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

and here what i tried to make the function return value

```
public static async void listDatabases(out List<string> lstListDB)
{
    List<string> lst = null;
    try
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
        //MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
        // List<string> lstdatabases = server.GetDatabaseNames().ToList();
        using (var cursor = client.ListDatabasesAsync())
        {
            await cursor.Result.ForEachAsync(d => lst.Add(d.GetElement(0).Value.ToString()));
            lstListDB = lst;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        lstListDB = null;
    }
}
```

it said i can't use out with async method any help thanks

Comment: Let the method return a `Task<List<string>>`. [Why you can't use `out`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716928/how-to-write-a-async-method-with-out-parameter)

Comment: you should always avoid if possible  a return  like  `async void`

Comment: i don't know it say you can use out with asynch method and for Task<List<string>> i couldn't do it ,any help please am just new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `out` in `async` methods as you have found. However, to return data from an async method simply have a return type of `Task<T>`. In your case:

```
public static async Task<List<string>> listDatabases()
```

Then you can just do the following in your method:

```
return lst;
```

You would then call it like:

```
var list = await listDatabases();
```

---

On a side note you should avoid a return type of `void` in `async` methods, instead you can use a return type of `Task`.

Comment: Right answer, it should be said, that using `async void` pattern means `fire and forget` call.
If the method then fails (throws exception) - no one will know

Comment: @Gh61: `async void` methods will re-raise any exceptions on their `SynchronizationContext`, which in many cases crashes the process. I like to call these "fire and crash" rather than "fire and forget".