# Async method which returns Task gives error cannot have ref or out parameters

Tags: c#

I get the following error. I did some searching and found out that I can solve this with `Tuple`. However, I am already returning `Task<Country>` from my function. In my code the out parameter returns `out List<Dictionary<string, int>>`. How can I alter my code so it also outs `out List<Dictionary<string, int>>` without affecting the existing functionality of the function. Help.

> Suppression State
>   Error Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters

```
 public async Task<Country> GetCountriesAsync(int countryId, ICollection<People> peeps, out List<Dictionary<string, int>> PresidentList)
{
      Dictionary<string, int> presi= new Dictionary<string, int>();
      presi.Add("presi", 1);
      PresidentList.Add(presi);
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716928/how-to-write-a-async-method-with-out-parameter

Comment: @DaisyShipton Yes. In my question I have said that I am returning `Country` already and don't know how to use a tuple. May be there's a different way or maybe I don';t understand how it is done. Can someone else help me here... ?

Comment: Learn to use a tuple.. the linked question @rui-jarimba supplied has an example.

Comment: @Dan haha. Yes Sir. I will!