# How does using await differ from using ContinueWith when processing async tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

Here's what I mean:

```
public Task<SomeObject> GetSomeObjectByTokenAsync(int id)
    {
        string token = repository.GetTokenById(id);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new SomeObject()
            {
                IsAuthorized = false
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return repository.GetSomeObjectByTokenAsync(token).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                t.Result.IsAuthorized = true;
                return t.Result;
            });
        }
    }
```

Above method can be awaited and I think it closely resembles to what the **T**ask-based **A**synchronous **P**attern suggests doing?  (The other patterns I know of are the **APM** and **EAP** patterns.)

Now, what about the following code:

```
public async Task<SomeObject> GetSomeObjectByToken(int id)
    {
        string token = repository.GetTokenById(id);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            return new SomeObject()
            {
                IsAuthorized = false
            };
        }
        else
        {
            SomeObject result = await repository.GetSomeObjectByTokenAsync(token);
            result.IsAuthorized = true;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

The key differences here are that the method is `async` and it utilizes the `await` keywords - so what does this change in contrast to the previously written method? I know it can too - be awaited. Any method returning Task can for that matter, unless I'm mistaken.

I'm aware of the state machine created with those switch statements whenever a method is labeled as `async`, and I'm aware that `await` itself uses no thread - it doesn't block at all, the thread simply goes to do other things, until it's called back to continue execution of the above code.

But what's the underlying difference between the two methods, when we invoke them using the `await` keyword? Is there any difference at all, and if there is - which is preferred?

**EDIT:** I feel like the first code snippet is preferred, because we effectively [elide](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) the async/await keywords, without any repercussions - we return a task that will continue its execution synchronously, or an already completed task on the hot path (which can be cached).

Comment: Very little, in this case. In your first example, `result.IsAuthorized = true` will be run on the thread pool, whereas in the second example it might be run on the same thread that invoked `GetSomeObjectByToken` (if it had a `SynchronizationContext` installed on it, e.g. it was a UI thread). The behaviour if `GetSomeObjectByTokenAsync` throws an exception will also be slightly different. In general `await` is preferred over `ContinueWith`, as it's almost always more readable.

Comment: In [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) it's called "eliding," which seems like a pretty good word for it. Stephen definitely knows his business. The conclusion of the article is essentially that it doesn't matter much, performance-wise, but there are certain coding pitfalls if you don't await. Your second example is a safer pattern.

Comment: You might be interested in this twitter discussion from the Partner Software Architect at Microsoft on the ASP.NET team: https://twitter.com/davidfowl/status/1044847039929028608?lang=en

Comment: It's called a "state machine", not a "virtual machine".

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you wise one, I forgot to edit that!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `async`/`await` mechanism makes the compiler transform your code into a state machine.  Your code will run synchronously until the first `await` that hits an awaitable that has not completed, if any.

In the Microsoft C# compiler, this state machine is a value type, which means it will have a very small cost when all `await`s get completed awaitables, as it won't allocate an object, and therefore, it won't generate garbage.  When any awaitable is not completed, this value type is inevitably boxed. <sup>1</sup>

Note that this doesn't avoid allocation of `Task`s if that's the type of awaitables used in the `await` expressions.

With `ContinueWith`, you only avoid allocations (other than `Task`) if your continuation doesn't have a [closure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/local-functions-vs-lambdas) and if you either don't use a state object or you reuse a state object as much as possible (e.g. from a pool).

Also, the continuation is called when the task is completed, creating a stack frame, it doesn't get inlined.  The framework tries to avoid stack overflows, but there may be a case where it won't avoid one, such as when big arrays are stack allocated.

The way it tries to avoid this is by checking how much stack is left and, if by some internal measure the stack is considered full, it schedules the continuation to run in the task scheduler.  It tries to avoid fatal stack overflow exceptions at the cost of performance.

Here is a subtle difference between `async`/`await` and `ContinueWith`:

- `async`/`await` will schedule continuations in `SynchronizationContext.Current` if any, otherwise in `TaskScheduler.Current` <sup>2</sup>
- `ContinueWith` will schedule continuations in the provided task scheduler, or in `TaskScheduler.Current` in the overloads without the task scheduler parameter

To simulate `async`/`await`'s default behavior:

```
.ContinueWith(continuationAction,
    SynchronizationContext.Current != null ?
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() :
        TaskScheduler.Current)
```

To simulate `async`/`await`'s behavior with `Task`'s `.ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
.ContinueWith(continuationAction,
    TaskScheduler.Default)
```

Things start to get complicated with loops and exception handling.  Besides keeping your code readable, `async`/`await` works with any [awaitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#awaitable-expressions).

Your case is best handled with a mixed approach: a synchronous method that calls an asynchronous method when needed.  An example of your code with this approach:

```
public Task<SomeObject> GetSomeObjectByTokenAsync(int id)
{
    string token = repository.GetTokenById(id);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new SomeObject()
        {
            IsAuthorized = false
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return InternalGetSomeObjectByTokenAsync(repository, token);
    }
}

internal async Task<SomeObject> InternalGetSomeObjectByToken(Repository repository, string token)
{
    SomeObject result = await repository.GetSomeObjectByTokenAsync(token);
    result.IsAuthorized = true;
    return result;
}
```

---

In my experience, I've found very few places in **application** code where adding such complexity actually pays off the time to develop, review and test such approaches, whereas in **library** code any method can be a bottleneck.

The only case where I tend elide tasks is when a `Task` or `Task<T>` returning method simply returns the result of another asynchronous method, without itself having performed any I/O or any post-processing.

YMMV.

---

1. When building for Release, the compiler generates structs.

   When building for Debug, the compiler generates classes to allow edit-and-continue on async code.
2. Unless you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or await on some awaitable that uses custom scheduling.

Comment: The state machine is not a value type. Take a look at the [generated source](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDMmMmcA7OgN7Lr3p0PHkBsmAHJuwLICGASwB2ACgCUTerSQNZmAJzcAdAE0BAUwA2wcfhkMAvgSRGkQA) of a simple async program: `private sealed class <Main>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine`. The instances of this class may be reusable though.

Comment: Would you say that if I were to tamper only with the result of a task, it'd be okay to use `ContinueWith`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, the [generated source](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEECsBuWsQGZlmQgHZEBvWRSxCq3QgNmQA5lGBZAQwEsA7ACgCUNSuRhVxyAJysAdAE0uAUwA2AE0GYxVAL5YYumEA===) targeting Release instead of Debug generates structs.

Comment: @SpiritBob, if you really want to fiddle with task results, I guess it's OK, `.ContinueWith` was meant to be used programmatically. Especially so if you're handling CPU intensive tasks instead of I/O tasks. But when you get to the point of having to deal with `Task`'s properties, the `AggregateException` and the complexity of handling conditions, cycles and exception handling when further asynchronous methods are invoked, then there's hardly any reason to stick with it.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information! I have a very silly question to ask, I couldn't find a concrete answer about it, but you seem to know what's up! If I were to cache a simple task returning an empty string, do I just create a static read-only field with a task generated by `Task.FromResult` in order to cache it and return it whenever necessary, or if I do that I'd effectively be sharing that object with multiple threads which only leads to nastiness - How to cache it then? If you could also share a resource in regards to those "cycles" you're talking about. First time hearing that term.

Comment: @SpiritBob, sorry, I meant "loops". Yes, you can create a static read-only field with a `Task.FromResult("...")`. In asynchronous code, if you cache values by key that require I/O to obtain, you can use a dictionary where the values are tasks, e.g. `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task<T>>` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary<string, T>`, use `GetOrAdd` call with a factory function, and await on its result. This guarantees only one I/O request is made to populate the cache's key, it awakes awaiters as soon as the task gets completed and serves as a completed task afterwards.

Comment: Regarding `ContinueWith`, if I'm passing a continuation that would instead start executing another task (because the first task has to finish first, in order to start the second task), should I configure it with `TaskContinuationOptions.RunSynchronously` to leverage some performance, or because it's not always certain if the task passed to complete is asynchronous or not (it has awaits that do suspend, regardless if they do I/O work or CPU-bound work, right?), to prevent a StackDive I should always use `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously`?

_PS: You're amazing._

Comment: `ContinueWith` already creates a `Task` that will execute after the previous task, so you must mean that the continuation itself starts another task; you probably mean an `async` continuation. If so, consider "infecting" the caller to become `async` as well and simply `await` the previous task. The typical solution to this case without infecting the caller is to use [`.ContinueWith(async ... => { ... }).Unwrap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap), which generates yet another `Task`.

Comment: Note that `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` is a **hint**, telling you'd like to execute in the same thread, while `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` actually **forces** your continuation to be scheduled.

Comment: In .NET, you shouldn't be worried about stack overflow when using `async`/`await`, the framework handles it pretty well. You should worry about it if you implement your own awaitables that use their own scheduling, so that the code that awaits on them doesn't have to worry.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Yeah, I was actually writing library code - a variant of [Interleaved](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-tasks-as-they-complete/). I modified it to accept an additionalContinuation, in the form of an async Func, and was wondering with what `TaskContinuationOptions` to start it. If I did `ExecuteSynchronously`, I'm not sure if it would have lead to a stack Dive, because the implemented continuation could have been synchronous. (If it was asynchronous, it wouldn't stack dive, right?) I ended up just using `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted`.

Comment: I couldn't find a way of adding another `TaskContinuationOptions`, so I left it at that! I'm also unwrapping a few tasks here and there, to make it as pleasant as possible for the user - instead of writing `await await` to get the task, they simply have to write `await`.

Comment: `TaskContinuationOptions` are flags, you may choose `None` for defaults, but you may also combine them, e.g. `TaskContinuationOptions.HideScheduler | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`. Regarding the unwrapping, when a task throws, its exception's stack trace will now include the continuation inside `Interleaved`, even though `Interleaved` had nothing to do with those exceptions at all; however, it simplifies its use a bit. I guess this compromise is not a bad one.

Answer (score 4):

By using `ContinueWith` you are using the tools that where available before the introduction of the `async`/`await` functionality with C# 5 back at 2012. As a tool it is verbose, not easily composable, it has a potentially confusing default `scheduler`¹, and requires extra work for unwrapping `AggregateException`s and `Task<Task<TResult>>` return values (you get these when you pass asynchronous delegates as arguments). It offers few advantages in return. You may consider using it when you want to attach multiple continuations to the same `Task`, or in some rare cases where you can't use `async`/`await` for some reason (like when you are in a method [with `out` parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716928/how-to-write-a-async-method-with-out-parameter/58165268#58165268)).

¹ <sub>If the `scheduler` argument is not provided, it defaults to `TaskScheduler.Current`, and not to `TaskScheduler.Default` as one might expect. This means that [by default](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) when the `ContinueWith` is attached, the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current` is captured, and used for scheduling the continuation. This is somewhat similar with how the `await` captures the ambient `SynchronizationContext.Current`, and schedules the continuation after the `await` on this context. To prevent this behavior of `await` you can use the `ConfigureAwait(false)`, and to prevent this behavior of `ContinueWith` you can use the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` flag in combination with passing the `TaskScheduler.Default`. Most experts [suggest](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) to specify always the `scheduler` argument every time you use the `ContinueWith`, and not rely on the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current`. Specialized `TaskScheduler`s are generally doing more funky stuff than specialized `SynchronizationContext`s. For example the ambient scheduler could be a [limited concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.exclusivescheduler) scheduler, in which case the continuation might be put in a queue of unrelated long-running tasks, and executed a long time after the associated task has completed.</sub>