# How do I access the variable of one method from another method within the same class C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm working on Asp.net project. I created a Form, which asks for `connectionId` and `holderFirstName` as Input. The name of asp-action is `SendProofNameRequest`.

In Controller, I wrote a Method `SendProofNameRequest` which take `connectionId` and `holderFirstName` as Parameters. But the problem is, the purpose I'm taking `holderFirstName` as Input is to use this in another Method (`VerifyFirstName`).

So, my question is how to take `holderFirstName` as input from user and use this in another method / `VerifyFirstName` (not `SendProofNameRequest`).

***Details.cshtml***

```
    <form class="input-group mb-3" asp-controller="Proof" asp-action="SendProofNameRequest">
        <input type="hidden" name="connectionId" value="@Model.Connection.Id" />
        <input type="text" name="holderFirstName" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name" aria-label="First Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Request a Proof of First Name</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

***ProofController.cs***

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendProofNameRequest(string connectionId, out string holderFirstName)
    {
        var agentContext = await _agentProvider.GetContextAsync();
        var connectionRecord = await _walletRecordService.GetAsync<ConnectionRecord>(agentContext.Wallet, connectionId);
        var proofNameRequest = await CreateProofNameMessage(connectionRecord);
        await _messageService.SendAsync(agentContext.Wallet, proofNameRequest, connectionRecord);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

***VerifyFirstName Method***

I want to replace `firstname` (static value) with `holderFirstName` (dynamic value / user entered in form)

```
    public bool VerifyFirstName(PartialProof proof)
    {
        var firstName = "Fyodor";
        var name = proof.RequestedProof.RevealedAttributes.First();
        if (name.Value.Raw.Equals(firstName))
        { 
            return true; 
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

As u said to add models, I did that... add the models in `ViewModel page` and call the `@model` in `View page`..

Now, to call the stored values in model in Verify methods controller.

`VerifyProof(string proofRecordId)` methods calls for another method `VerifyFirstName(proof)` which does the actual verification.

Kindly have a look at code and can u point out where to add `model.HolderFirstName` and `SendNameRequestViewModel model` in which method e.g. `VerifyProof(string proofRecordId)`, `VerifyFirstName(proof)`.. I was getting an errors..

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyProof(string proofRecordId, SendNameRequestViewModel model)
    {
        var agentContext = await _agentProvider.GetContextAsync();
        var proofRecord = await _proofService.GetAsync(agentContext, proofRecordId);
        var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProofRequest>(proofRecord.RequestJson);
        var proof = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PartialProof>(proofRecord.ProofJson);
        bool verified = false;
        switch (request.Name)
        {
            case "ProveYourFirstName":
                verified = VerifyFirstName(proof, model.HolderFirstName); break;
            default:
                    break;
        }
        if (!verified)
        {
            proofRecord.State = ProofState.Rejected;
            await _walletRecordService.UpdateAsync(agentContext.Wallet, proofRecord);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public bool VerifyFirstName(PartialProof proof, SendNameRequestViewModel model.HolderFirstName)
    {
        var firstName = model.HolderFirstName;
        var name = proof.RequestedProof.RevealedAttributes.First();
        if (name.Value.Raw.Equals(firstName))
        { 
            return true; 
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If I understand correctly, you're having issues with how functions work. Just pass the first name as a parameter to your verify method from your SendProof method. You may need to create a second verify method since I'm not sure what PartialProof type is.

Comment: can't do that, asp-action is `SendProofNameRequest`, the name of the method should be  also `SendProofNameRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the actions/methods in the controller class are meant to handle requests coming from the client to the server. They're not just methods in a class.

Hence I think you need to take out `out` keyword from the parameter `holderFirstName`. Or better, to use a view model to pass between the view and the controller:

```cs
public class SendNameRequestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string HolderFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class ProofController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendNameRequest(string connectionId)
    {
        // Initialize the view model if needed, i.e., filling its ConnectionId either
        // from query string or cache. I don't know how you get the connectionId

        var agentContext = await _agentProvider.GetContextAsync();
        var connectionRecord = await _walletRecordService.GetAsync<ConnectionRecord>(agentContext.Wallet, connectionId);
        if (connectionRecord == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var vm = new SendNameRequestViewModel
        {
            ConnectionId = connectionId
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Then on the view, you declare its model as `SendNameRequestViewModel` so that you don't have to hard code the input names/

Notes: I've also added validation summary and validation message for inputs.

```
@model SendNameRequestViewModel

...

<form class="input-group mb-3" method="post" asp-controller="Proof" asp-action="SendNameRequest">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ConnectionId" />

    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>

    <input asp-for="HolderFirstName" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" 
      placeholder="Enter First Name" aria-label="First Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span asp-validation-for="HolderFirstName" class="text-danger"></span>

    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Request a Proof of First Name</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

For your `VerifyFirstName` check, there are so many way to do it. You can directly run its logic in the controller action body, for example. I would create an extension method against `PartialProof` object:

```cs
public static class PartialProofExtensions
{
    public static bool VerifyFirstName(this PartialProof proof, string firstName)
    {
        if (proof == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var name = proof.RequestedProof.RevealedAttributes
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return (name != null && name.Value.Raw.Equals(firstName));
    }
}
```

When the form is posting back, you can just run the validation check in the action method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiforgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendNameRequest(SendNameRequestViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var agentContext = await _agentProvider.GetContextAsync();
        var connectionRecord = await _walletRecordService.GetAsync<ConnectionRecord>(agentContext.Wallet, model.ConnectionId);
        if (connectionRecord == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModalError("", "Invalid connection Id.");
            return View(model);
        }

        var proofNameRequest = await CreateProofNameMessage(connectionRecord);
        if (!proofNameRequest.VerifyFirstName(model.HolderFirstName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModalError(nameof(model.HolderFirstName), "Invalid first name.");
            return View(model);
        }

        await _messageService.SendAsync(agentContext.Wallet, proofNameRequest, connectionRecord);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: first thanks for your response.. let me past the code (complete pages), it will be more easy for you to understand my scenario

Comment: ProofController.cs -> https://pastebin.fun/HSABpXyrPY
ProofsViewModel.cs -> https://pastebin.fun/VLkepDvAkC

Comment: it didn't solved because, I want to take input from user in `holderFirstName` in view page, store this in variable and use it in `VerifyFirstName` method.

Comment: @MattGreen: so does that mean in the `VerifyFirstName` function, you can't pass the first name as string parameter?

Comment: that's my point.. I used `var firstName = "Fyodor";` (static value) as an example, and want to replace this value ("Fyodor") with `holderFirstName` (user input value).

Comment: I already tried to use `out` reference, but can't use with async methods -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716928/how-to-write-an-async-method-with-out-parameter

Comment: I want to use `string holderFirstName` as parameter in `VerifyFirstName`, which stores the value entered by user in form.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? That's what I exactly did: `if (!proofNameRequest.VerifyFirstName(model.HolderFirstName))`. `model.HolderFirstName` is the input from the user.

Comment: yes, I tried this.. but there is one problem and that's why I sent u the code in pastebin, so u can look at complete page..

Comment: in this code -> https://pastebin.fun/HSABpXyrPY, in the bottom `VerifyProof(string proofRecordId)` methods calls for another method `VerifyFirstName(proof)` which does the actual verification...

Comment: my question is if you look at the code (in pastebin), can u point out where to add `model.HolderFirstName` and `SendNameRequestViewModel model` in which method e.g. `VerifyProof(string proofRecordId)`, `VerifyFirstName(proof)`.. I was getting errors..

Comment: can u please help? I've been trying but no luck... I updated the code... have a look

Comment: I don't know how to help you. I mean I don't know what you're working on. I highly recommend you to take a deep look on the codes I pasted and try to understand how things work. Just by looking at your codes in pastebin, I have no idea what's going on, which actions are GET methods that prepare the view models to the views, which ones are POST methods that take the returned view and process things, because your naming conventions are off, for example, I see `SendProofRequestNameView()` and `SendProofNameRequest()`. I am not sure if they both work on the same view.

Comment: thanks for ur time, just have a look at the updated code (in the question section above).. i'm following ur code.. but my last problem is why I'm getting error, when calling a values stored in model in controller page.. now, problem is with verify methods (2, one calls another)... that's it..

Comment: @MattGreen: why did you have the view model as the parameter in a HttpGet method? The view model is supposed to be built in the HttpGet method and return it to the view. Then on the form post, the HttpPost method will capture the view model as the parameter (thanks for the model binding) and you work on your logic to verify, save, etc.

Comment: sorry for can't explaining my point correctly, but thanks for ur time :)