# Is there a good way to handle private static fields in a generic type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, static

I am trying to figure out a way I can make use of `private` `static` fields in a generic `class`. This is the obvious way to do it ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P7moyR)). It won't compile because `Field` is not accessible in `BaseChild`, and ideally I wouldn't want it to be accessible there:

```
public class Base<T>
{
    private static readonly string Field = "field";

    public Base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Field);
    }
}

public class BaseChild : Base<string>
{
    public BaseChild()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Field);
    }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that there is a different `Field` for each generic type, instead of being shared across them.

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665168/5335355) where it says that JetBrains recommends a solution for `static` fields across generic types:

> If you need to have a static field shared between instances with different generic arguments, define a non-generic base class to store your static members, then set your generic type to inherit from this type.

This makes sense for the case where you have `public` or `protected` `static` fields in the `base` class that you want to share across any child `class` like this example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XeaqEB)):

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected static readonly string Field = "field";
}

public class Base<T> : Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Field);
    }
}

public class BaseChild : Base<string>
{
    public BaseChild()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Field);
    }
}
```

However, what about the case where you want to use a `private` `static` field? I would guess that this is not possible since `private` means only accessible to the `class` it's declared in and I think that since the generic `class` is really just a template to create a `class`, that any `private` field could only ever be shared by each `class`, not across all the classes created by the template.

Do I have to just put the `private` field in the generic class (example 1) and accept it as at least a workable solution for what I want, or is there another way I can accomplish this?

Comment: IMHO, declaring something as `protected static` in unsealed class is essentially the same as `public static`. `protected` does not really give any protection for static members.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree. It keeps other non-child classes from accessing or mutating the field. Also, protected doesn't even really make any sense in a sealed class. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: *It keeps other non-child classes from accessing or mutating the field.* Yes, but it does not stop anyone from declaring their own child classes just to access `protected static` members.

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's what `protected` is meant for.

Comment: @PetSerAl I'll take what you said into consideration. But, regardless, whether I set it to public or protected in my example, it doesn't change my question. I think that I have come up with an [alternate solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42965978/5335355) though, that doesn't use `public` or `protected`.

Comment: Are there any issues with my solution, or something I may have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I came up with that I think actually does what I want better than the initial example I put in my question. It shares a single static field across all the generic types, and it is inaccessible from children of the Base generic class.

```
public static class Base
{
    private static string Field = "field";

    public class Base2<T>
    {
        public Base2()
        {
            // Field is accessible here, but is the same across all generic classes
            Console.WriteLine(Field);
        }
    }
}

public class BaseChild : Base.Base2<string>
{
    public BaseChild()
    {
        //Field is not accessible here, and I don't really want it to be
        //Console.WriteLine(Field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off -- `private` is doing exactly what it's made to do: to restrict access to only the type it was declared in. Keep in mind that instantiations of a generic type are all distinct types. You shouldn't be wanting to work around this.

If I understand your question correctly, you can accomplish what you want by using `protected` with an extra level of inheritance:

```
class EvenMoreBase
{
    protected static readonly string Field = "field";
}

class Base<T> : EvenMoreBase
{
    public Base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Field);
    }
}

class BaseChild : Base<string>
{
    public BaseChild()
    {
    Console.WriteLine(Field);
    }
}
```

Now each of your `Base<T>` will share the same instance of `Field`.

Comment: Yeah, I just wasn't sure if I was missing something. I'm leaning towards just having the field be private in the generic anyways, because for my actual case, I don't think the child classes should have access to the field I'm using. I would rather not just assume that no child class will touch the field.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in your thoughts on `private` within the base class. Whether it is static or not makes no difference.

Here's a little example:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Bar b = new Bar(); // Prints "Foo"
        // Console.WriteLine(Foo.BaseField); // Compile error
    }
}

public class Foo 
{
    protected static readonly string BaseeField = "Foo";
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Foo.BaseeField);
    }
}
```

Marking it protected is useful, if you'd like only your children to be able to access it. And leaving it `static` is how you'd keep only one instance around for all children of the base `Foo` class.