# How does this comparer C# syntax work?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0

I see the following syntax:

```
var comparer = Comparer<TItem>.Default;
```

How does this syntax work?

I would have thought that the `Comparer` would have to be new'd up

Comment: Which syntax you talking about exactly? You mean generics?

Comment: @shiva Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037203/are-static-members-of-a-generic-class-tied-to-the-specific-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to not having to new up a Comparer explicitly is that Default is a property, and properties are allowed to have code. This applies to static properties as well:

```
static Comparer<T> Default {
    get {
        ...
        return new ClassExtendingComparer<T>();
    }
}
```

This amounts to a parameter-less factory method accessed using a field/property syntax.

Answer (score 5):

`Default` is a static property, and because of that can be access without having an instance of `Comparer<T>`.

> A static member cannot be referenced through an instance. Instead, it is referenced through the type name.

`Comparer<TItem>` is a type name here.

Comment: So it is a generic accessor property which calls a method under the hood and not a static data field. And this means the property can use the specified type dynamically to lookup the default comparer?

Comment: It is a property, not a field, so yes, it can execute code.